# How do I link two Java files together during compilation using GCJ?

Tags: java, gcj

My apologies as I'm very much a "Java noob." Anyways, I think I've dumbed this problem down sufficiently to ask in a way that is straight-forward and will get me the answer I want. Let's say I have two files, both in my home directory, as follows:

**Test.java:**

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Test2.test();
    }
}
```

and **Test2.java:**

```
class Test2
{
    public static void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Now if I leave these files as is, when I run "`gcj Test.java --main=Test`", naturally I get an error saving Test2 is undefined. But I have no idea what I need to add to tell it where to find Test2. I tried adding "`import Test2;`", "`import Test2.*;`", and "`import Test2.java;`" to the top of Test.java, but clearly I'm not on the right track here. What do I need to do to link these files together and get it to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Stuff about classpath removed) gcj doesn't follow normal java rules

Use:

```
gcj *.java --main=Test
```

instead of what you supplied, it works.

But still--put your stuff in packages and specify a classpath for anything beyond testing.

Better yet, use Eclipse with a [gcj plugin!](http://gcjbuilder.sourceforge.net/)